# Digital input reading 0

Tags: python, arduino

I'm learning to program and use Arduino. I am trying to create a simple circuit that returns the reading of a thermistor. I've attached my circuit diagram and code. My issue is instead of getting a useable value from the thermistor, it prints a list containing two zeros. Any potential solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance. [image]

```
from pymata4 import pymata4
import time

THERMO_PIN = 7

board = pymata4.Pymata4()

board.set_pin_mode_digital_input(THERMO_PIN)

value = board.digital_read(THERMO_PIN)

print(value)

board.shutdown()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are reading in a binary way (digital_read). You should use analog read to get an analog value, because digital_read only returns either 0 or 1.
So, the functions you need are `set_pin_mode_analog_input` and `analog_read`

**UPDATE:**

You also need to connect to a pin that is capable of analog input. Those are the pins A0 to A5. If you connect to A0, the THERMO_PIN should be 0. If you connect it to A1, THERMO_PIN should be 1 and so on.

**UPDATE 2:**

As I see it, the pymata4's analog_read only outputs the *difference* between the current and previous detected value. The difference is 0 in your case, because you didn't put in any sleep and the value is thus the same as the previous read value. It seems like a better way is to do it with a callback. Here is the tutorial:
https://github.com/MrYsLab/pymata4/blob/master/examples/analog_input_with_time_stamps.py

Comment: thanks for your response. I've made these changes but I still have the same issue. `from pymata4 import pymata4
import time

board = pymata4.Pymata4()

board.set_pin_mode_analog_input(0)

value = board.analog_read(0)

print(value)

board.shutdown()`

Comment: @iHaveAQuestion I have edited the answer. But you should do `board.set_pin_mode_analog_input(THERMO_PIN)  value = board.analog_read(THERMO_PIN)` instead of `board.set_pin_mode_analog_input(0)  value = board.analog_read(0)`

Comment: @mbsotic I apologise I've just read the updated bit of your answer and have change the value of THERMO_PIN to 14 (it is in the A0 pin slot and was previously entered as 0). Now I get an error "IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: @iHaveAQuestion Sorry, I was wrong. try setting the THERMO_PIN to 0 if you are connected to A0

Comment: thanks very much mate thats working now @mbostic

Comment: @iHaveAQuestion great. Can you please accept the answer if that is the case?